# Change element in a set via iterator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, set

I want to change an element in a set (QSet):

```
for(PSet::iterator pIt = P.begin(); pIt != P.end(); ++pIt)
  pIt->xp = 0;
```

The compiler won't let me do this ("C3892: 'var' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const"). It seems like a set iterator is always constant due to fear that changing the element might corrupt its proper position in the set.

In my case PSet is a set of structs for which I defined my own hash function:

```
struct P
{
  P(int id, const Data_t& data)
     :xp(_INFINITY_)
     ,id(id)
     ,data(data){}

  int xp;  
  const int id;
  const Data_t data;
};
```

My hash function does not consider the non-const member xp, so my above assignment should be perfectly safe concerning the element's order in the set. I do not want to remove the element and re-insert it, since performance is actually an issue here.

I guess I could use const-casts but that would hurt my code's readability and look like a nasty hack. 
Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying  `QSet` elements is not allowed, since it could break set internal structure of the container by modifying one of the hash result.

As for the standard associative containers, this in the standard section § 23.2.4

> iterator of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator
>   category. For associative containers where the value type is the same
>   as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are constant
>   iterators. It is unspecified whether or not iterator and
>   const_iterator are the same type.

If you know that your modification has no impact on the sorted position element, the use of a `const_cast` is one of those rare case where it is ok.

However, the idiomatic way is to use an **hint insertion** :

1. Locate the element to be modified
2. Make a copy of the element
3. Modify the copy
4. Remove the element
5. Insert the copy, using the hint insertion when available (there is non for a `QSet`)

**Example:**

```
  s.erase(original);
  // modify p ...
  s.insert(copy, hint);
```

Notes :

1. The same apply for the other associate containers.
2. This issue is extensively discussed in "*Effective STL , Item 22*", Scott Meyers.
3. It is sometimes a good idea to consider `std::vector` as a substitute for `std::set`

Comment: QSet insert does not take a hint. Probably because it is hash-table based. What about using mutable for the member I want to modify instead of several const_casts in different places?

Comment: it doesn't matter is a particular member is mutable and if other members are not : you could still have const_cast modifying non mutable elswhere : the compiler has no way of knowing that  _ looks like you are left with const_casting your set elements then  (I edit about using `hint` when available )

Answer (score 0):

The elements of a `set` can't be duplicates. If you'd be allowed to change an element, then all this logic wouldn't be maintained. Therefore, you need to erase the existing element and insert the new one.

So unless you use `const_cast`, there's no other way to do it. However, as mentioned, doing so may break the `set`, allowing it to have potential duplicate values.

Here's how one would do it for a `std::set<int>` (I know it's not a QT set, but the logic should be the same):

```
std::set<int> mySet;
mySet.insert(3);
mySet.insert(4);
for (auto i = mySet.begin(); i != mySet.end(); i++)
{
    int* elem = const_cast<int*>(&*i);
    *elem = 6;
}
```

Comment: QSet is a hash-table based set. It's elements are not sorted.

Comment: OK, thanks for the headsup. I'll leave only the relevant stuff in my answer, and clear the sorted related :)

Comment: @user2079303: The same logic applies; the hashes would need to be re-calculated, and directly modifying the value will not do that. So, you have to use the interface that the set exposes to you. It's basically the difference between getters/setters and direct member access. This is _not_ just about "duplicates".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Hash would not need to be re-calculated if the modification does not change the hash value such as in the case of OP. Of course, aLu would also have to implement the equality operator so that `xp` does not affect the equality of the objects, thereby preventing duplicates when modifying only that member. That would be pointless though, since QSet does not give non-const access to the stored objects (and no general purpose set should because of the problems already mentioned).